# Is it possible to load a canvas in a xml defined view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-canvas

I want to have a View where i can draw when the user touches that view. I have read that you can create a subclass of View, redefine some methods like onDraw and then load that view in your xml layout.

My problem is that i need to handle the touching events not only for that view, so i have to handle them from the Activity, so if it is possible, i would like to load a generic View in the layout without creating a custom view, and then, under those events, create a Canvas, draw on it, and then assign that canvas to the generic View.

Is this possible, or I should try to handle this problem using the first approach?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the first approach. You can still add a listener to handle touch events from your activity as usual with [`setOnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29).